# Paypal buttons integration

Tags: paypal

Good morning, i have to create a landing page that gives the possibility to the user to book an pay with paypal buttons a limited training course.
Is the a way to make the paypal button interact?
I know that it is the possibility to set a stocking for the single product, but what i need to know is if it is possible to create a grouped product that change the stocking values of the others.
(example: if i buy the product a that has a 25 pieces stock, it will low the stock of the product b too)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can track your inventory with PayPal buttons. Refer to the link below for the guidelines on creating Yes, you can track your inventory with PayPal buttons.

Refer to the link below for the guidelines on creating a button on your account.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/create_payment_button/
a button on your account.

Comment: The link you provided is now 404 not found